# Why my if condition is not working in python unnesting function?

Tags: dataframe, python-3.6

I have written an unnest function in Python3.6 as below-

```
full_df = unnest(full_df,'Options','product code')
def unnest(df, col, col2,reset_index=False):
   for item in df[col]:
       if len(item)==0:
           item=item.append('')

   col_flat = pd.DataFrame([[i, x]
                  for i, y in df[col].apply(list).iteritems()
                      for x in y ], columns=['I', col]
                       )
   col_flat = col_flat.set_index('I')
   df = df.drop(col, 1)
   df = df.merge(col_flat, left_index=True, right_index=True)

   if reset_index:
      df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

   if df[col] is None:
      merchant_product_code = df['Product code']
   else:
      merchant_product_code = df['Product code'] + '-' + df[col]
  df['item_group_id'] = df['Product code']
  df['Product code'] = merchant_product_code
  return df
```

Problem I am facing here is, in case of Options value as []; it is removing the [] with empty and in Product Code column it is adding a hyphen(-) after product code.

I have converted my dataframe full_df as dictionary here so that you can test it.

```
{'Product code': {0: 'BBMTG', 1: 'BBDBPSD', 2: 'BBDBPEL', 3: 'BBDBPDR', 4: 'BBFTDR', 5: 'BBFTPBG', 6: 'BBFTPBS', 7: 'BBFTEY'}, 'Category': {0: 'Essentials', 1: 'Bedding /Bamboo Blanket', 2: 'Bedding /Bamboo Blanket', 3: 'Bedding /Bamboo Blanket', 4: 'Apparel', 5: 'Apparel', 6: 'Apparel', 7: 'Apparel'}, 'List price': {0: 8.9, 1: 45.0, 2: 45.0, 3: 45.0, 4: 28.0, 5: 28.0, 6: 28.0, 7: 28.0}, 'Price': {0: 8.9, 1: 45.0, 2: 45.0, 3: 45.0, 4: 28.0, 5: 28.0, 6: 28.0, 7: 28.0}, 'Options': {0: '[]', 1: '[]', 2: '[]', 3: '[]', 4: "['0-3m', '3-6m', '6-12m']", 5: "['0-3m', '3-6m', '6-12m']", 6: "['0-3m', '3-6m', '6-12m']", 7: "['0-3m', '3-6m', '6-12m']"}}
```

Can anyone look into this and help to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to solve my issue by changing below line-
item.append('[]')
and
df['Product code'] += df[col].apply(lambda val: '' if val == "[]" else '-' + val)